# Zend_Form : Use images instead of text labels?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I'd like to replace the common input's labels with some images.
I have a multicheckbox with a country list, and I want to display for each checkbox the country flag instead of it's name.

I tried to put an `<img/>` tag as label value, but this html is escaped and displayed as text instead of displaying the images...

Is there a native solution ? Should I create a custom decorator ?

I'm currently trying to create a custom decorator but I'm noob and I'm pretty sure there is an other cleaner way for this ! Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found by myself... It was so  simple that I didn't even think about it.

When you create a form element, it's possible to set the option `escape` to `false` :

```
$this->addElement('multiCheckbox', 'countries', array(
    'filters'    => array(/* some filters */),
    'validators' => array(/* some validators */),
    'label'      => 'Countries :',
    'decorators'  => array( /* some decorators */ ),
    'escape'     => false, /* will prevent the checkboxes' labels to be escaped */
));
```

As my checkboxes' labels aren't escaped anymore, I can set some html  inside :)